# Using foreach and map to iterate over lists in Netlogo

Tags: list, foreach, netlogo

I just started learning netlogo a couple of days ago and would appreciate some help. I have a list called "distance", which gives me the distance from each patch in a given radius to a current patch. I want to plug in each value of "distance" into the following, to get an "attractiveness" value for each patch:

`Patch attractiveness = exp ((distance / 800) * (log e (.2 / 1)))]`

I would like to store these values in another list called "patch_attractiveness." I think I should use either `map` or `foreach`, but I do get the error "Nothing named d has been defined." Below is what I have tried:

`let Patch_attractiveness map  [d -> distance] exp ((d / 800) * (log e (.2 / 1)))]`

I think my confusion is primarily with how to use anonymous procedures.

Comment: Coming in late, but feel a need to mention that `distance` is a NetLogo primitive, so you can't have a list named distance.  Also, rather than building the list twice, you can use the OF command to get the patches to report their attractiveness directly. It's been a month, you probably know that, now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was where you placed distance and the fact that you have two closing brackets but only 1 opening bracket.
When using `map`, the order goes; `map [anonymous procedure] list`

```
let Patch_attractiveness map  [d -> exp ((d / 800) * (log e (.2 / 1)))] distance
```

`Foreach` is a bit different in the order and also requires some extra steps to make the list you need. For `foreach`, it goes: `foreach list [anonymous procedure]`.
`Foreach` does not return a list so you need to make that one yourself.

```
let Patch_attractiveness []
foreach distance [d -> 
   let this-attractiveness exp ((d / 800) * (log e (.2 / 1)))
   set Patch-attractiveness lput this-attractiveness Patch-attractiveness
]
```

Anonymous procedures can feel a bit weird so I encourage you to just keep playing around with them to get used to the syntax.